# declare a generic using Type class (C#)

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to cast from the object to List , where I know the 'T' at runtime. Is there is any way to cast or any other solution to it

//This return an object by default ,but in runtime returning `List<T>`

```
var getList = modelClass.GetValue(modelObject);
```

Now , **getList** is not allowing to use Linq properties coz of this.

I know the Type (T) (getting dynamically through code)

Is there any work around to cast this like :

```
var getList = (List<typeClassObject>))modelClass.GetValue(modelObject);
```

Kindly please help on this

Comment: `var getList = (List<T>))modelClass.GetValue(modelObject);` If this doesn't work, you are using generics incorrectly.

Comment: In what way do you know `T` at runtime? As a `Type` instance, or as a generic parameter in your method? What did you research show?

Comment: @CodeCaster yes as Type i know ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `modelClass.GetValue(modelObject)` returns and `IEnumerable<someType>`, you should be able to do the transformation as follows:

```
var getList = modelClass.GetValue(modelObject)
                 .Select(obj => ((object) obj) as typeClassObject);
```

`getList` is now an `IEnumerable<typeClassObject>`

Doing:

```
var getList = modelClass.GetValue(modelObject)
                 .Select(obj => ((object) obj) as typeClassObject)
                 .ToList();
```

would have `getList` being `List<typeClassObject>`

Comment: The method returns an `object`.

Comment: if it merely returns object you are stuck with the explicit casting